# Find when Firebase data has been uploaded after coming back online

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am writing an Android/Cordova/Firebase app which needs to work offline. I have data objects which are updated; I simply update them and use [Firebase Database's offline features](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities) so that they are uploaded when the app comes back online. That works fine. The problem is that the items also involve blobs which I need to upload to Firebase Storage. I want to somehow be alerted when a pending update is sent to the server, so that I can initiate the upload to Firebase Storage.

Of course I can manage the online/offline status myself with a queue of pending Firebase Storage uploads, but is there any way to have Firebase tell me when a pending update to the database has been made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built into the Firebase SDK to signal when it is completely in sync with the server. In the past I've recommended writing a dummy value from the client when it's back online and having a listener that wait for that dummy value to show up. Once you get that dummy value, you're guaranteed to have also received updates that were written before it.